# Improve the query performance

Tags: sql-server

Initially there is 2 tables involved

col1 - Int
Col2 -int

select * from table inner table2 on table.col1=table2.col2

-- Fine it give result in short time in a 2 minutes

But after change the col2 to nvarchar(30)
select * from table inner table2 on table.col1=convert(nvarchar(30),table2.col2 )

-- its running more  than a hours

Any solution to optimize the query

Comment: By adding an expression to the `WHERE` clause (or a `JOIN` condition as in this case) your query is no longer SARGable and any indexes become useless, which effectively **destroy** performance as you've noted. Either keep both sides of the `JOIN` as `INT`, or change them both to strings, so that the conversion isn't necesary in either case.

Answer (score 0):

Joining 2 tables using an nvarchar(30) will be slower than an int column as it is bigger.  I would stick with using int if possible.